# MAVEN: NoClassDeffFoundError

Tags: android, maven

I am using android studio, **MAVEN 3.0.5**, **JDK1.7** on a **MS Windows 8.1 PC**.
although it looks (to me) that i have done all the appropriate settings for maven it wont work. I was using **MAVEN 3.1.1** with no problems, but now I need to go back to 3.0.5 for the project I work on. My M2_HOME is set and **mvn --version** command produces the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher
```

the whole error is:
    C:\Users\iakovos\workspace\UserprofileProject\Userprofile>set M2_HOME
    M2_HOME=C:\apache-maven-3.0.5\apache-maven\src

```
C:\Users\iakovos\workspace\UserprofileProject\Userprofile>mvn --version
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/c
lassworlds/launcher/Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.lau
ncher.Launcher
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
.  Program will exit.
C:\Users\iakovos\workspace\UserprofileProject\Userprofile>
```

anyone with more experience, that could help me? 
thank you!

Comment: What does your path point to?

Comment: @DanielBrbarian to the  maven files under the src file. There are the bin, conf, lib, main, site and test folders

Comment: i don't mean your M2_HOME. I mean your PATH on your machine.

Comment: I havd correclty included the M2_HOME in my PATH as well as the JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> set M2_HOME M2_HOME=C:\apache-maven-3.0.5\apache-maven\src

You are setting the M2_HOME variable to the source folder? This might be the problem set it to the root folder of your Maven installation, where you find the `bin`, the `boot`, the `conf` and the `lib` folder.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I have downloaded the source zip and not the binary zip. It looks like this was the problem. As soon as I downloaded the binary zip it worked! I mark this as my accepted answer as it was the one who took me there! Thank you